# Get param from shortcode in plugin function

Tags: plugins, shortcode, parameter

I am trying to get the variable passed in my shortcode so I can do a request with the id to a API.

The shortcode looks like this: `[product id="2"]`

In my function I want to do something with the "2".

Code so far:

```
function getSingleProduct( $attr ) {
    shortcode_atts( [
      'id' => '0',
    ], $attr  );

    // Do someting with the "2".
    do_request( 'GET', get_api_url() . 'api/product/' . "2" ); // This "2" comes from the shortcode
}

add_shortcode( 'product', 'getSingleProduct' );
```

Comment: Where you have `// Do something with the "2"`, just do something with it, I think I don't understand your question. Can you try to explain the problem deeply?

Comment: @cybmeta Thanks for the reply. See updated answer. Maybe I don't even need the `shortcode_atts();` I am totally new to this.

Comment: I've seen the update *question* already, no much more information so far.

Comment: I don't know how to explain the problem more deeply than I already did... The 2 in the shortcode gets passed in the function of that shortcode the 2 needs to change according to the shortcode, so when i use `[product id="3"]` the 2 needs to be a "3". And the request will go according to the param in the sortcode.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this shortcode:

```
[product id="2"]
```

Which is redered by this:

```
add_shortcode( 'product', 'getSingleProduct' );
function getSingleProduct( $atts ) {
    shortcode_atts( [
      'id' => '0',
    ], $atts  );

    // Do someting with the "2".
    do_request( 'GET', get_api_url() . 'api/product/' . "2" ); // This "2" comes from the shortcode
}
```

You can get the shortcode params like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'product', 'getSingleProduct' );
function getSingleProduct( $atts ) {
    // $atts is an array with the shortcode params
    // shortcode_atts() function fills the array with the
    // default values if they are missing
    $atts = shortcode_atts( [
      'id' => '0',
    ], $atts  );

    $id = $atts['id'];

    do_request( 'GET', get_api_url() . 'api/product/' . $id );

}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid, if i knew $atts was an array with the param as key this wasn't an issue. Thanks for putting me in the right direction.